# composer dump-autoload --optimize only load classes for one package

Tags: composer-php, autoload

In the same project I have these two `composer.json` files:

```js
{
    "name": "kingsoft/persist",
    "description": "Object Persistance",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kingsoft\\Persist\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

and

```js
{
    "name": "kingsoft/http",
    "description": "Http Request/Response handler",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kingsoft\\Http\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

The folder structure is :

```
- vendor
  - kingsoft
    - http
      - src
        Request.php
      composer.json
    - persist
      - src
        Base.php
      composer.json
```

The problem is that only the `Persist` class is loaded, not the `Request` class.

What is the reason for autoload skipping the classes in the HTTP package?

Comment: What's your question about this configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "not loaded"? There's no code given that would load any class

Comment: @NicoHaase I realise that. But from context it is possible to deduct intend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Strict naming rules in PSR-4

Although the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard is not entirely clear on that naming under PSR-4 is quit strict. I assume a not PSR-4 conform name problem.
The namespace for **Persist** probably is `Persist` and works the one for **http** quite likely but incorrectly `HTTP`.

### Solution

Rename the namespace of the sources in the `http` packages to `Http`.

Comment: Thsnks for the downvote. Please include a comment